# Does farming need government support to work efficiently?

Tags: economy, india, germany, agriculture

In 2020, there were farm law protests in India, related to [concern of farmer losing certain government support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Indian_agriculture_acts) from Indian govt.

I thought this was maybe due to India being a third world country and related reasons.

Now, recently protest for the same fundamental reason manifested in a different form is happening in Germany [here](https://www.stripes.com/theaters/europe/2024-01-08/farmers-protest-convoy-germany-12597043.html).

So, I am wondering, why is that even with all these technologies that the farmers are still so sensitive to government policy change? Are farms fundamentally dependent on a stable government existing to function?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in the general sense of all farming output? Or would you want to focus on a specific product/would an answer focused on a singular type of farming be relevant? As I understand, it can be rather situationally dependent, as while Canada for example has a [dairy-associated quota system](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/canada-supply-management-explainer-1.4708341) - their dairy, poultry, and egg farming sectors are the specific sectors targeted with that supply-managed system, as opposed to a subsidy-based system.

Comment: "can't really work out at all" That needs a bit of more explanation, I think. You mean like, we are all going to starve and die? Because for example Germany is very far from it. I think this question should clarify exactly what "doesn't work out" means here.

Comment: Farming has worked without subsidies for thousands of years (although there also have been famines for thousands of years). So, the trivial answer would be "Farming can work without subsidies (but that might require changes to the economic system)." What research have you done? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultural_subsidy) might provide a starting point.

Comment: And the protests in Germany are not because the government wants to abolish all farming subsidies. They are about a comparibly small part of the total farming subsidies.

Comment: You should add some more details on how you tentatively conclude that "farming requires state support" from two incidents of farmers protesting some government decision, and what you mean by support (financial support such as subsidies, changes in regulations, something else?). There are, e.g., worker's protests and other political demonstrations in many countries, and one reason plausibly is that state decisions (such as taxation or regulation) influence many aspect of civil and commercial life.

Comment: While a somewhat weaker standard, farming requires the existence of functional governments to protect property rights and to insure a lack of disruption in the exchange of goods for money. Historically, some of the first farming societies were command economies where the products were distributed on the basis of a ration system by chiefs of chiefdoms.

Comment: No.  New Zealand reformed a lot of its farming away from state support in the 80s/90s(?).  That's unusual, because farmers are usually a very strong lobby in Western democracies, but it is not the death knell of farmers.  At the end of the day, people do have to eat.  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:GEJO.0000019969.38496.82

Comment: The German protests were triggered by the plan to scrap certain subsidies (reduced taxes for agricultural vehicles and fuel). Clearly, this implies a higher tax load, which is unfavourable for a farm, just as it would be for any other sector, even though it is plausibly well justified from general principles. I feel there could be a good question here along the lines of "Is farming more strongly influenced by regulations/Why is that/Why do farmers for a strong lobby", but the differences between India, germany and other countries should be acknowledged and are likely substantial.

Answer (score 6):

Lots of the industry have been moved from developed countries into less prosperous countries where the work costs less, regulations are more relaxed and the like. There is no reason why farming, agriculture should be any different, especially when some other country where farming is cheaper for any reasons is not very far. Farming may also be cheaper for some objective reasons like climate or more suitable land. With cargo ship taking about a month from China to Europe, many products have long enough life time to be moved around the globe no problem.

Countries generally do not like to lose the ability to feed the own population as this makes them dependent from other countries. Due that many developed countries do support they farmers to make they products competitive.

Hence the local farming may need governmental support to work not that "efficiently" but be competitive against the import.

Comment: Industrialization has made centralized production including agriculture vastly more efficient than older decentralized models.  Yet some markets like food represent such a potential threat to domestically, that governments around the world subsidize this segment to allow smaller domestic options to compete against their more efficient centralized rivals.   Many do this including.   It's not a factor of Agriculture needing government to work effectively, it's more a factor of governments requiring agriculture, which is an entirely different discussion.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to already satisfactory answer:

Industrial farming may be very efficient. Small countries such as Netherlands and Israel can cover significant share of international vegetables production market. This is compounded by the fact that overseas shipping is reliable and cheap.

However, in the existing countries there is a significant farmer population, who already live in the countryside, pay taxes there that keep the infrastructure running, providing military manpower, and in general "manning the ground". If they are allowed to be outcompeted completely, the farmland will hollow out, with potential security implications as well. Moreover, since there's not a great assortment of available occupations in the countryside, there would be significant farmer unrest if they are allowed to go bankrupt. This in comparsion with cities where new jobs are usually generated faster than old ones go, or at roughly the same ratio.

Therefore, most of the countries try to strike a balance between large, industrial-scale latifundia which are often located abroad, and local farmers. To do so, they need subsidies to be distributed between the latter, and limitations on the imports of the former. For example, it's almost impossible to bring/import processed foods into the EU from the outside, as far as I know.

Local farmer communities are also recognized as a source of local traditions, unique cuisines and general *know how*, that culture would be lost or signficantly degraded if they are allowed to disperse. If such protective measures are not taken then farming is likely to suffer in any country, replaced by huge agricultural enterprises being more efficient with resource allocations by only going for highest value crops.

This has started in XIX century where the railroad ensured a lot of produce can be just moved to the big industrial cities from the less densely populated, more fertile southward regions. This would lead local farming to become uncompetitive, with farmers suffering to keep their lifestyle and often flocking to the cities as economic refugees.

Comment: Farmers get significant state support in most first-world countries, even those otherwise committed to free-market economics. The EU spends a large part of its budget on farm subsidies. The US government spends [$30bn a year](https://www.cato.org/briefing-paper/cutting-federal-farm-subsidies) on farm subsidies. Canada has subsidies and tariffs to protect its farmers. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

No.

New Zealand, back in 1984, un-subsidized most of their agriculture and liberalized it.  Keep that in mind next time you are shopping for kiwis or mutton.

[New Zealand’s Agricultural Reforms
and their International Implications](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/david.harvey/AEF318/318.2/NZReformsJohnson.pdf)

> NEW ZEALAND IS ONE OF THE FEW COUNTRIES IN THE
> OECD and elsewhere to abandon price support systems for its
> agricultural sector and to embark on a free trade policy for
> agriculture. Starting in 1984, subsidy programmes for agricultural
> products were discontinued or phased out as part of a general
> reform programme for the economy. The effects of the programme
> have been to improve productivity in the agricultural sector particularly and to encourage growth in the rest of the economy.

[Removal of agricultural and fisheries subsidie](https://www.cbd.int/doc/case-studies/inc/cs-inc-newzealand-technical-en.pdf)

> By 1995, farm land prices had recovered to 86 percent of their pre-reform levels. Today, the
> agriculture sector is larger than when it was heavily supported; it is more profitable, efficient and
> innovative. The meat industry has developed from the least efficient to the second most efficient
> in the world. Employment in the sector has actually increased. The rural economy has diversified
> to include tourism and other services which have made rural communities less vulnerable to
> cyclical downturns in agriculture. The support of farmers’ organizations and consumer groups
> contributed greatly to reform success.

[(pub 2003?) Revolution or evolution? New Zealand agriculture since 1984 | GeoJournal](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:GEJO.0000019969.38496.82)

> Agriculture was the primary target of moves to deregulate the New Zealand economy in 1984. Within twelve-months all production subsidies had been removed, including those for fertiliser and other inputs, as well as funding for drought relief, floods and other natural weather disasters. **Whereas at the start of 1984, subsidies were estimated to represent as much as 33% of farm income, by 2003 this had fallen to less than 2% with most of this spent on agricultural research.** The anticipated shift of thousands of people off the land did not appear to occur, and by conventional measures at least New Zealand agriculture in 2003 is a major success story. At the core of the changes imposed on agriculture was **a commitment to remove all state or government distortions from the system and to fully expose the agricultural sector to market forces.** This included wide-ranging and fundamental changes in the broad institutional context within which agriculture must operate. **All this was achieved at great social cost** and with a significant impact on the environment. In many respects New Zealand agriculture is now very different from that in 1984. Some sectors, such as dairying, have grown and become increasingly industrialised. On the other hand, sheep farming, particularly for wool has struggled to maintain its market share, while other enterprises have emerged as significant sources of income, including horticulture, viticulture and fruit. It is argued here that the trends evident in New Zealand agriculture since 1984 pre-existed the reform period and that the apparent success of the reforms evident at a national scale have not addressed or removed the fundamental problems which face New Zealand agriculture, just as they do modern agricultural systems elsewhere.

It wasn't painless.  People sold farms and they were consolidated.  Farming's share of [GDP fell off](https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/New-Zealand/Share_of_agriculture), though it was dropping before, and though farming GDP and employment trending down is symptomatic of nations getting richer overall.

But NZ still has farmers and still exports.  The claims made about competing cheap labor are not as applicable to farming as to many other industries because much of the poorer parts of the world also have challenges to deal with:

- Farming land is not that productive in the South or they have high populations to feed (India, China).  Certain crops grow in certain places, not in others.
- High populations with limited land and lots of farming employment means small, inefficient, farms.
- Much of modern farming requires a lot of equipment and capital investment. And cheap labor can be managed via guest worker programs (which have their own issues, certainly).

The main reason seems political in nature.  Farmers are a well-organized, well-connected, vocal, and sympathetic lobby in most Western nations (as well as India apparently).  Much of our population has ancestral roots to farmers at some point, food is a necessary for life and has deep emotional resonance.  Even as subsidies generally flow to the biggest producers, the industry romanticizes "saving the small family farm". This makes cutting off subsidies a political suicide in most countries.

Look no further than those doughty defenders of free markets and small government, US farmers in the Midwest.  And look at the massive subsidies they get for ethanol, at best a very dubious way to reduce emissions to fix a problem the region's voters deny exists in the first place.

Comment: "All this was achieved at great social cost and with a significant impact on the environment" charitably one might say that politicians would like to avoid those two things

Answer (score 1):

First, you must understand the nature of agriculture. It isn't like a factory that can be turned off and back on.

For farms to produce food efficiently, they must be kept in production. Shut down a farm, stop growing food for a year or two, and it can take a couple of years or more to bring it back up to full production. You need the mechanization to produce efficiently, and the support organizations to get the produce to the population. Both will be in short supply if not in constant use, further delaying crop production.

On top of that delay, crop based agriculture runs on a 1 year cycle: plant in the spring, harvest in the fall. Can't just walk out in a field and start plucking produce.

Food is the most strategic of resources for a nation. Without food... people starve. You can live without a lot of modern conveniences, but you cannot live without food.

In times of conflict, nations can find their imports curtailed. Or... a nation that relies heavily upon imported food will find itself at the risk of having that food supply threatened as a very effective political weapon. Doesn't even have to be hostile - a friendly nation can get a lot of concessions if they are the primary food supplier to another nation that doesn't produce enough to feed its people.

A nation that finds its external food supplies threatened can't just turn its own farms back on. Takes a couple of years at least to get full productivity, while people can starve to death in a few weeks.

Thus the need for government supports: to keep the farms producing, and negate the possibility of a food cutoff. Governments do this by guaranteeing the farmer a price for their products, so that the farm remains economically viable.

This will see the farmer through rough times - bad weather reducing crop production, or low cost imports rendering their farms unprofitable.

Is this just a theoretical issue, or is it real? Consider the [Dutch Famine of 1944-1945](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_famine_of_1944%E2%80%931945). The speed with which the famine set in after a 3-4 week German embargo of food shipments should bear ample witness as to how quickly a nation can run out of food if it is dependent upon imports.

This is especially relevant as there has been a movement within the Netherlands to shut down farms as 'producing too much CO2'.

The Dutch, of all people, should remember what that can lead to.

Answer (score -1):

No, not in the slightest.

Agriculture is dependent on the Sun, rain, wind, soil conditions, local ecology, technology, labors and diligence of the farmers, and so on. It is not dependent in any sense on governments other than by **non-intervention** in allowing people their right to own and occupy land and till it, and to use water and other resources as they see fit, and **protecting all those rights**.

The best thing governments can do is go hands-off and let farmers produce and keep the fruits of their labors. Unconstitutional regulation is the worst thing that ever happened to farmers.

In the United States, there is no enumerated power anywhere in the Constitution that grants any government power to meddle or intervene in the process of raising, harvesting, processing storing or selling crops, other than ensuring fair weights and measures and uniform definitions are used if the commercial standards of multiple states are involved in a transaction.

Comment: The last bit is easiest to disprove. The courts already established that selling crops falls under the Commerce Clause. That's pretty much obvious from the name of that clause.

Comment: @MSalters The Commerce Clause is one of the most legendarily abused clauses in the Constitution, tortured into granting the federal government virtually unlimited and godlike power, despite clear and obvious limitations conveyed in its wording. Even under the most expansive conceivable interpretation, it grants governments no power at all to meddle in crop raising and selling where state boundaries are not crossed. You just fell into this trap yourself.
https://www.heritage.org/the-constitution/report/commerce-commerce-everywhere-the-uses-and-abuses-the-commerce-clause

Comment: @MSalters The very word "regulate" means "to make uniform or regular", as in for example, fixing weights and measures to enable fair trade. It does not in any sense mean "to make whatever laws controlling or disposing of other men's property as oneself sees fit". Because of the illiteracy of recent generations, the word "regulate" has been lost and replaced with expansive, self-contrary mush. Because of the ignorance of the people towards such a basic word, it was inevitable that we have lost many freedoms. https://scholarship.law.georgetown.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1504&context=facpub

Comment: -1 The word "regulate" does not appear in the Q.  Nor does the word "constitutional" or the tag USA.  The question is simply whether subsidies are necessaries - most free marketers would say no.  Regulation... yes, because obviously *regulation* to [keep say pigs from harboring worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichinella_spiralis#Prevention_and_control) is an affront to the natural order of things.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The question is basically about the nature of farming, and incidentally about government. My answer is truthful and valid.